# How to align SwiftUI view height to its overlay view height

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-view

I have this corresponding structure of a view:

```
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            CostumShape()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10, corners: .allCorners)
                .overlay {
                        VStack {some other views...}
                }
         }
```

Right now my CustomShape takes almost the entire available height - wheres the Overlay needs half of it. I need my CustomShape height to have the same height as Overlay height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.overlay(alignment: .top)` let overlay view align to CostumShape.

```
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.red
                                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                            Text("Other views")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                }
         }
```

[image]